# Simple array of objects sort is not working properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

Array is not sorting properly. I am sorting the objects based on id , I have written in correct way only

but it is not sorting at all.

```
 list = list.sort((item1, item2) => {
        return item1.id > item2.id ? 1 : -1;
      });
```

the sample array of objects are like this

```
0: {baseCalendar: {…}, id: "0"}
1: {baseCalendar: {…}, id: "1"}
2: {baseCalendar: {…}, id: "10"}
3: {baseCalendar: {…}, id: "11"}
4: {baseCalendar: {…}, id: "12"}
5: {baseCalendar: {…}, id: "2"}
6: {baseCalendar: {…}, id: "4"}
7: {baseCalendar: {…}, id: "5"}
```

Comment: use `parseInt()`. Also comparisons should return -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: In case the first comment is not clear enough: you're sorting strings instead of integers

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your ids are Strings, not Numbers, but you are comparing them as Numbers.

You have to convert them to Numbers, while you are comparing them, for examples as:

```
list.sort((item1, item2) => { return +item1.id > +item2.id ? 1 : -1; });
```

Or using `parseInt(item1.id, 10)` and `parseInt(item2.id, 10)` as proposed above.

Comment: could be just `list.sort((item1, item2) => item1.id - item2.id)`